# How to know tabbar tab was pressed?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar based app.  In the app delegate, I've implemented:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[TabBNavigationController class]]){
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc postNotificationName:@"TabBClicked" 
    object:self userInfo:nil];}
```

and fire off a notification.  ViewB is displayed when tabB is pressed.  ViewB is inside a UINavigationController.  The problem is ViewB's viewWillAppear fires before the above event.  I need to know TabB was clicked before ViewB's viewWillAppear fires.  Is there another way to get in front of viewWillAppear in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`, this method should be called before any view gets visible.